# Kibana "Available fields" not showing (string) fields inside array

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

My problem is that I cant see all my fields in the "Available fields" section of the discover page in Kibana.

When I populate my elasticsearch database with the following data:

```
    {
    "user": "a",
    "data": [
       {
       "string1":"abc",
       "string2":"abc",
       "date": "2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z"
       }
     ]
    }
```

Both the "user" field and the "date" field inside the array will show up but not the two strings "string1" and "string2".

Instead the array "data" is shown with a value like:

> [{"string1":"abc","string2":"abc","date": "2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z"}]

If I choose "show missing fields" as well I can see the "string1" and 2 fields but get the error message:

> this field is present in your elasticsearch mapping but not in any
>   documents in the search results

But clearly both fields exists and contains data.

Running Elasticsearch and Kibana Version 7.1.1

Thanks!

Comment: did you manage to fix it? Are you able to show all available fields in discover screen?